# Matlab String Split when it is a String object

Tags: string, matlab

The other answers for similar question works if the string is str1 = 'MynameisJohn' within single quotes. For example, str1(1:2) gives 'My'.

But if the string is str1 = "MynameisJohn" with double quotes, the above usage str1(1:2) does not work and gives an out of bounds error. The size of str1 in this case is just a 1 by 1 matrix.

In the second case, how do I split the string to get the words in it, assuming there are no whitespaces (hence delimiters can't be used). We can assume the lenghts of my split are constant.

EDIT
I think I found the answer myself. str2 = char(str1) converts the string array str1 to a character array and then similar constructs str2(1:2) works.

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? I'm using R2016b and double quotes give a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

Conversion to char and then indexing works as you have posted. If you would like the result to stay as a string another way to extract substring is to use extract functions. For example,

```
str1 = string('MynameisJohn');
substr = extractBefore(str1,3)

substr = 

  string

    "My"
```

In this case substr is still a string type. Doc for extractBefore is at https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/extractbefore.html

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you using? I'm using R2016b and double quotes give a syntax error.

Comment: You are right. I copied a line from the question. I edited the answer.